# C++ Help with setf floatfield from string

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
*mit = 13311
std::istringstream iss(*mit);
double temp;
iss.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
iss.precision(15);
iss >> temp;

std::cout<<"temp "<<temp<<endl; 
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<temp / 1024;
```

I had tried with / without set precision, I still got 12.999, instead 12.9990234375
Please advise what did I do wrong? Thanks.
Andrew

Comment: Hm, where did you try to set precision? And what you want to do, you expect `ss` to be "12.9990234375" ?

Comment: ss is stringstream. I did same to ss<<std::setprecision(10)<<temp / 1024; It worked. Thanks again, Kirov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `std::setprecision( 15 )` in the `cout`

```
 std::cout<< "temp " << std::setprecision( 15 ) << temp <<endl;
```

---

**EDIT**: sorry, if I got you wrong. You expect to see `12.9990234375` printed or you expect `ss` to be `12.9990234375` ? If the second, then make:

```
ss << std::setprecision(15) << temp / 1024;
```

Comment: Yes, setprecision in cout or stringstream worked nicely. Thanks a lot.